# Unexpected results using cryptoJS hmacMD5

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, md5

I have set up some encryption using cryptoJS library like so:

**Adding more code following comments**

Here is the script in full, I'll ask our vendor to provide a new secret

```
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-md5.js"></script>

<script>

var now = new Date().getTime();
var aid = 1941816;
var sid = {{trialpay cookie values}}.sid;
var user = {{user id}};
var query_string = '?tp_aid=' + aid + '&tp_sid=' + sid + '&tp_t=' + now;
// query_string var during instance in question was this = '?tp_aid=1941816&tp_sid=U1281574706&tp_oid=103060921&tp_t=1435078629604'; 

// hash md5
var key = '8b2b7d7dc4063bc0bf30986536f8816c71405c16fb0cc4677db1e349af157baa';
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacMD5(query_string, key);
hash = hash.toString();

//passback
var tp_img = document.createElement('img');
tp_img.height=1;
tp_img.width = 1;

//tp_img.src = "https://tpc.trialpay.com/" + query_string +  "&tp_v1=" + hash;


tp_img.src = "https://tpc.trialpay.com/?tp_aid=" +  aid +
                           "&tp_sid=" + sid +
                           "&tp_oid=" + encodeURIComponent(user) +
                           "&tp_t=" + now + 
                           "&tp_v1=" + hash;

document.body.appendChild(tp_img);

</script>
```

During the instance of testing in question, I know that the var being hashed, `query_string`, was this value:

```
?tp_aid=1941816&tp_sid=U1281574706&tp_oid=103060921&tp_t=1435078629604
```

The output that our vendor received was this value:

```
727a9075e3c8e7a7758e3f6a0369a476
```

They told me that they expected this value:

```
60eadcb01f3f04a3d7169a1dd0199943
```

When I check the output in my own environment using console.log(), I get the expected value. So I don't know how they got the value ending in 476.

This is all that I know. Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if there is any other info I can provide on this.

Comment: No. Can you show the two differing MACs? If not, are you sure it's not an issue of Base64 vs. Hex encoding?

Comment: Hi @ArtjomB. thanks for responding. I'm not sure how to answer your question. How would I check that?

Comment: char encoding also makes a difference, notably UTF (js) vs non-UTF (others)

Comment: The rollups of CryptoJS have different encodings included. Hex is always included, but Base64 not always. So when you use `hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)`, CryptoJS might silently fallback to Hex if Base64 is not available. But I think dandavis is right in that the key and querystring might be differently encoded. We can't be sure, because you haven't provided enough information/code.

Comment: Other idea: the key is wrong. When passing as string, it is expected to be utf8 encoded. If you want it to be hex encoded, you will have to do it yourself: key=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('8b2b...')

Comment: Hi @ArtjomB. thanks for the advice. I tried your recommendation but still did not get the result I was looking for. Interestingly, when I reverted to my original script I was unable to recreate the results I was getting yesterday evening.